# How to make a list of lists from two lists

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to accomplish the following task and failing so far. I have two sorted lists of numbers. Say

```
A = [5.8, 6.5, 7.6, 14.5, 18.1, 25.7, 26.4, 30.7, 30.9, 33.6, 38.6, 38.8, 39.2]

B = [9.0, 13.5, 22.5, 32.3 40.6, 43.2, 47.9, 54.2, 60.3, 63.0]
```

I want to make a list of lists. Each list contains a different value from B and all the values in A between that B-value and the one directly before it in the list. The first list just contains everything smaller than the first value in B.

So in this case the list of lists should start

```
[[5.8, 6.5, 7.6, 9.0], [13.5], [14.5, 18.1, 22.5], [25.7, 26.4, 30.7. 30.9, 32.3]....]
```

I would be happy with numpy code if that is simpler/faster.

I tried:

```
[[*a, b] for b, a in itertools.groupby(A, lambda x: next(filter(lambda y: y >= x, B)))]
```

but it misses out all the singleton lists and I am not sure how fast it is in any case.

Comment: Since the resulting lists vary in length, this is not a good fit with `numpy`. Just use list operations.  Don't worry about speed at this stage.  For a start I'd just iterate on `b`, collecting the relevant values from `a`.  Don't try anything fancy.

Comment: This doesn't look easy to "vectorize", which is what `numpy` is usually for. Actually, all your lists will be jagged, so that's another issue. If you really want this to work within numpy, consider writing a C extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use two pointers like this,

```
i = 0
j= 0
ans = [] #contains the lists of lists
while j<len(B):
    to_append = []
    while i<len(A) and A[i]<=B[j]:
         to_append.append(A[i])
         i=i+1
    to_append.append(B[j])
    ans.append(to_append)
    j=j+1
```

Try now

Comment: At least for this example, this list approach is much faster than the `numpy` ones.

Comment: This will run a bit faster using `for b in B` in place of the `j` iteration.  I've also tried to replace the `i` iteration with an iterator on `iter(A)` or a generator, but so far without success.

Comment: This is just vanilla logic. I am sure we can vectorize it too. I'll try that and add an edit later today

Answer (score 3):

You can use `heapq.merge` for an O(n+m) solution:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
from heapq import merge

[*map(list, map(chain, map(iter, repeat(merge(A,B).__next__), B), zip(B)))]
# [[5.8, 6.5, 7.6, 9.0], [13.5], [14.5, 18.1, 22.5], [25.7, 26.4, 30.7, 30.9, 32.3], [33.6, 38.6, 38.8, 39.2, 40.6], [43.2], [47.9], [54.2], [60.3], [63.0]]
```

This uses `merge` to merge A and B in order. Next, the two argument form of iter is used to split at the elements from B. This unfortunately eats the split points, so we reattach them using itertools.chain.

Answer (score 2):

you could do,

```py
import numpy as np
A = [5.8, 6.5, 7.6, 14.5, 18.1, 25.7, 26.4, 30.7, 30.9, 33.6, 38.6, 38.8, 39.2]
B = [9.0, 13.5, 22.5, 32.3, 40.6, 43.2, 47.9, 54.2, 60.3, 63.0]
A = np.array(A)
B = np.hstack(([-np.inf], B))
result = [np.r_[np.extract((A>B[i]) & (A<= B[i+1]), A), B[i+1]] for i in range(len(B)-1)]
```

and if you want just lists, you could do afterwards :

```py
result = [*map(lambda x : list(x), result),]
print(result)
# [[5.8, 6.5, 7.6, 9.0], [13.5], [14.5, 18.1, 22.5], [25.7, 26.4, 30.7, 30.9, 
# 32.3], [33.6, 38.6, 38.8, 39.2, 40.6], [43.2], [47.9], [54.2], [60.3], [63.0]]
```

Comment: This creates a lot of empty arrays. [array([], dtype=float64),
 array([5.8, 6.5, 7.6]),
 array([], dtype=float64), etc.

Comment: There should not be empty lists.  The answer should look like [[5.8, 6.5, 7.6, 9.0], [13.5], [14.5, 18.1, 22.5], [25.7, 26.4, 30.7. 30.9, 32.3]....]

Comment: Your answer has two `result` lines. The first one gives: [array([-inf]),
 array([-inf]),
 array([5.8, 6.5, 7.6, 9. ]),
 array([13.5]), etc

Comment: It works just fine , maybe you didn't copy it right

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you.

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Use np.searchsorted to solve the problem in O(N*logN) time.
First, find position of elements from B in A. Next, split array A using those postions. Finally create a list of desired properties.

```
pos = np.searchsorted(A,B)
chunks = np.split(A, pos)
res = [np.hstack(ab) for ab in zip(chunks,B)]
```

This will generate the required list of ndarrays which you can convert back to list using ndarray.tolist() method:

```
res_list = list(map(np.ndarray.tolist, res))
```

Answer (score 1):

As a purely Numpy-based approach (not that significant tho) you could convert your lists to array and do the following:

```
In [43]: ind = (b[:,None] > a).sum(1)

In [44]: np.split(np.insert(a, ind, b), ind + np.arange(1, ind.size +1))
Out[44]: 
[array([5.8, 6.5, 7.6, 9. ]),
 array([13.5]),
 array([14.5, 18.1, 22.5]),
 array([25.7, 26.4, 30.7, 30.9, 32.3]),
 array([33.6, 38.6, 38.8, 39.2, 40.6]),
 array([43.2]),
 array([47.9]),
 array([54.2]),
 array([60.3]),
 array([63.]),
 array([], dtype=float64)]
```